# Java JSlider not showing up after JFileChooser is used

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfilechooser, jslider

When I use JFileChooser then try to add other components, they don't show up. If I remove JFileChooser they do show up. I'm writing in java on eclipse, and there are two files.

I have removed a majority of my code to simplify the problem, but it still exists.

Main.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        int width = 1280;
        int height = 720;

        Frame f = new Frame(Color.BLACK, width, height);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title"); //create a new window and set title on window
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //set the window to close when the cross in the corner is pressed
        frame.setSize(width,height);

        frame.add(f); //add the content of the game object to the window
        frame.setVisible(true);

        long interval = (long)10 * 10000000;
        long t = 0;
        while(true) {
            if(System.nanoTime() - t >= interval) { //repaints at a certain fps
                t = System.nanoTime();
                f.repaint();
            }
            TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Frame.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame extends JPanel {
    int menuNum = 0;
    boolean first = true;

    JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(0,255,0);
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    public Frame(Color background, int w, int h) throws IOException { //initialize
        this.setBackground(background);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics G) {
        super.paintComponent(G);

        G.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        G.drawString("MenuNum: " + menuNum, 1000, 500); //for debugging

        if(menuNum == 0) { //first menu
            if(first) { //only run once
                first = false;

                this.removeAll();
                this.add(nextButton);

                System.out.println("HERE");
            }
            if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { //if "Done" is selected
                menuNum = 1; //go to next menu
                first = true;
            }
        }

        if(menuNum == 1) { //second menu
            if(first) { //only run once
                first = false;

                this.removeAll();
                this.add(nextButton);
                this.add(slider); //<This is the slider that is not showing up

                System.out.println("HERE2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are running this on your own machine, you can select any file to test it, since it does nothing with the selected file.

I am somewhat new to JPanels and JFrames so any advice will be well appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: DO NOT, EVER, modify the state of the component from within the `paintComponent` method - you clearly do not understand how custom (or the how system) painting works. You need to go back to basics, starting with [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: What is the functionality you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is absolutely no reason to do any custom painting. You should never try to add/remove components from a JPanel in a painting method.

The components should be added to the panel in the constructor of your class. So this means the button should be added to the panel.

Then you add an `ActionListener` to the button. When the button is clicked you do some processing.

If you want to alter the components on the panel in the `ActionListener` then the basic logic is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

So you need the `revalidate()` to invoke the layout manager. Otherwise the size of the added component is (0, 0), which means there is nothing to paint.

Learn Swing basics by reading the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). Maybe start with section on:

1. How to Write an ActionListener
2. How to Use Sliders
3. How to Use CardLayout (instead of adding/removing components).

Answer (score 0):

Just follow same idea, you will get

```
public MyControlPanel() {
    initComponents();
    JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);

    JTextField boundary_length = new JTextField("Boundary Length");
    JTextField area = new JTextField("Area");

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    this.add(slider);
    this.add(area);
    this.add(boundary_length);

}
```

Comment: But the problem is that even if I call "this.add()" the component still does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found the solution with the updateUI() method. Look below:

```
private void refresh()
{
   if(slider != null)
        {
           slider.updateUI();
        }
}
```

So, when your JFilechooser closing you must call the refresh() thus:

```
if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == 0 // this is the value for JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        { //if "Done" is selected
            menuNum = 1; //go to next menu
            first = true;
        }
else    {
            refresh();
        }
```

I hope this should works.